# For what values of z is the following statement true?

Tags: complex-analysis

$(e^{iz})*$=$e^{iz}$*

The star means conjugate. On the LHS, the star is outside of the parenthesis. I'm not sure if that would just make the $i$ negative or distribute to both the $i$ and the $z$. On the RHS, the star only applies to the $z$, which makes sense to me. That means instead of $x+iy$ I'm going to get $x-jy$. But what scenario would allow these to equal? This is what I came up with so far:

$(e^{iz})*$=$e^{iz}$*

$e^{-i(x+iy)}=e^{i(x-iy)}$

$e^{-ix}e^y=e^{ix}e^y$

$e^{-ix}=e^{ix}$

$cosx-i*sinx=cosx+i*sinx$

$0=2sinx$

$x=+or- n(pi),$ where n=any integer

Does that make sense??

Comment: That's what I got too!  See below....

Answer (score 0):

$e^{iz} = e^{ia} e^{-b}$ where $z = a + bi$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, so conjugation would leave $e^{-b}$ alone and conjugate the $e^{ia} = \cos(a) + i \sin(a)$ leaving $e^{-ia}e^{-b} = e^{-iz}$, since $-\sin(a) = \sin(-a)$.  Further,

$$
e^{-iz} = e^{iz^*}
$$
iff 
$$-iz = i z^* + 2k\pi i$$
for some integer $k$.

Algebraic manipulation and real-part formula $Re(z) = \frac{z + z^*}{2}$ gives that your two versions are equal iff $Re(z) = k\pi$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial analysis is correct:

$e^{-iz}$ = $e^{-i(x+iy)} = e^{-ix}e^y$, whereas $e^{i\bar{z}}$ = $e^{i(x-iy)} = e^{ix}e^y$.

That means we need $e^{ix} = e^{-ix}$ and this is true only if $x = 2n\pi$, where n is an integer.

The conclusion is that z must lie on one of the (vertical) lines $x = n\pi$, since any value of y is okay.

Your answer is nearly there you didn't quite state what the z's are.

Comment: $e^{3\pi i} = e^{-3\pi i} \ $.  Go around 1.5 full circles, then go around -1.5 full circles and you're at the same spot.  So it *is* $k\pi$ for any integer $k$.

Comment: @EnjoysMath quite true -- late at night one gets a bit fuzzy.  Thanks for the correction.